# Serving index.html with Node's st module

Tags: node.js, express, static-files, node.js-connect

*In short: how can I get `st` to serve `index.html` when I visit `/`?*

I'm using the [st module](https://github.com/isaacs/st) with Express (or Connect, doesn't matter). Here's the entirety of my code:

```
var st = require('st');
var path = require('path');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect();

app.use(st({
  url: '/',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  index: 'index.html', // !!! PROBLEM LINE !!!
  cache: false,
  passthrough: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.end('This is not served from the st module.');
});

app.listen(8000, function() { console.log('App started.'); });
```

When I visit `localhost:8000/index.html`, I see the file. When I visit `localhost:8000/`, I do *not* see the index HTML.

I've tried the following for the `index` option, with no luck:

- `index: false`
- `index: true`
- `index: 'index.html'`
- `index: 'public/index.html'`
- `index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html')`

How can I get `st` to serve `index.html` when I visit `/`?

Comment: Why not use `connect.static`?

Comment: Strange, index: true or index: 'index.html' - both work fine for me.

Comment: @robertklep connect.staticCache is going to be deprecated soon, but I'm using it for now.

Comment: From the module's [readme](https://github.com/isaacs/st), it seems that the path needs to be slash-terminated. Can you try that?

Comment: @EvanHahn but `connect.static` isn't, is it?

Comment: @robertklep No, not as far as I know. But I want to add caching (eventually).

Comment: @verybadalloc Tried that, no luck.

Comment: Your code works for me, exactly as you’ve shown it. I can get both `/` and `/index.html`. You’ve probably done this but: have you cleared your browser cache? And what happens if you use `curl` instead of a browser to request the page?

Answer (score 0):

I implement a redirect, something like:

```
routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/index.html');
};
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Move your `index.html` to directory public. Because `st` deals the request as following:

```
 if (u.indexOf(this.url) !== 0) return false
```

which means the URL you current visiting must be a sub-URL of the option `url` set by `app.use()`.

In this example, you are mapping the `'/public'` to `'/'`. So, you can't use `public/index.html` unless you create another folder named `public` under the original `public` folder and put the `index.html` in it.

You can't use `../index.html` either since `st` don't allow this (you are visiting a unmap file!) and you will got an `403` error.

If still failed, try another web browser. Once I try on **Chrome** all right ,but failed on **Firefox**. That's perhaps caused by the cache option.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
st({ 
    path: __dirname + "/web", 
    url:"/", 
    index: "/index.html" 
});
```

Worked for me. But I had to clear my browser cache first.